# Getting users job title in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

So I have a SP Online list, that every user can submit his entries. I have a default column of "created by", where the user, that submited the entry is listed. I'd like to have 2 other columns, to get users Department and Job Title copied automatically from users account. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Method 1:
   You can use the JSOM to set the Department/JobTitle. Because we don't sure where your user from(AD or some else )

First of all you need to load the “SP.UserProfiles.js, SP.Runtime.js and SP.js” js files on your SharePoint page, use following code snippet to load these files,
$(document).ready(function () {

```
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", 
    function () { 
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", 
           function () { 
               $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.UserProfiles.js", GetUserInformation);
            }); 
    });
```

});

```
var userProfileProperties;

function GetUserInformation() {


// Get the current client context.

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class    

    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
    var targetUser = "domain\\userId";
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);



    //Execute the Query.   

    clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);    }



function onSuccess () { 
    // get user information from userProfileProperties and set to your target column. 
   userProfileProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
   userProfileProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['SPS-JobTitle'];
```

// To do: list item replace operation
    }

```
function onFail (sender, args) { 
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message()); 
}
```

Reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700.aspx

2. Method 2: Workflow

   When user add/edit a item,we trigger the workflow to copy the user's department/JobTitle to target column

Reference for get the Department/Jobtitle.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97971/get-current-user-information-and-add-to-email-action-in-workflow